# ¿Es posible poner un WHERE alternativo a una consulta tomándolo de otra tabla en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Tengo una consulta que me trae varias filas agrupadas dentro de un rango.

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(bcee.v, ' ', bcee.t) SEPARATOR ' ') texto
FROM liturgia l
    LEFT JOIN liturgia_misa_lecturas lml ON l.id_celebracion=lml.id_celebracion
    LEFT JOIN biblia_pericopas bp ON lml.id_pericopa=bp.id_pericopa
    LEFT JOIN biblia_pericopas_aux bpa ON bp.id_pericopa=bpa.id_pericopa
    LEFT JOIN biblia_libros bl ON bp.id_libro=bl.id_libro
    INNER JOIN bibliacee bcee ON bl.id_libro=bcee.l
WHERE  
    bp.id_pericopa=613 AND 
    l.id_celebracion=542 AND  
    lml.orden =40 AND 
    ((bcee.l=bp.id_libro AND bcee.c >= bp.capitulo AND bcee.v >= bp.v_inicial AND bcee.v <= bp.v_final) )
GROUP BY l.id_celebracion,bp.id_pericopa, lml.orden
ORDER BY l.semana, l.dia, lml.orden, bcee.c, bcee.v
```

Mi problema está en los últimos criterios de la consulta que son estos:

```
... AND  bcee.l=bp.id_libro AND 
         bcee.c >= bp.capitulo AND 
         bcee.v >= bp.v_inicial AND 
         bcee.v <= bp.v_final
```

Ahí yo busco textos dentro de un rango que comprenden uno o varios capítulos y dentro de esos capítulos unos versículos.

Por ejemplo este es un resultado, porque el rango iba del versículo `14` al `22`:

> 14 Llamó Jesús de nuevo a la gente y les dijo: «Escuchad y entended
>   todos: 15 nada que entre de fuera puede hacer al hombre impuro; lo que
>   sale de dentro es lo que hace impuro al hombre».
>  16 Cuando dejó
>   a la gente y entró en casa, le pidieron sus discípulos que les
>   explicara la parábola. 17 Él les dijo: «¿También vosotros seguís sin
>   entender? ¿No comprendéis? Nada que entre de fuera puede hacer impuro
>   al hombre, 18 porque no entra en el corazón sino en el vientre y se
>   echa en la letrina». (Con esto declaraba puros todos los alimentos).
>   19 Y siguió: «Lo que sale de dentro del hombre, eso sí hace impuro al
>   hombre. 20 Porque de dentro, del corazón del hombre, salen los
>   pensamientos perversos, las fornicaciones, robos, homicidios, 21
>   adulterios, codicias, malicias, fraudes, desenfreno, envidia,
>   difamación, orgullo, frivolidad. 22 Todas esas maldades salen de
>   dentro y hacen al hombre impuro».

Todo lo anterior funciona perfectamente.

Ahora viene mi problema.

En la tabla `biblia_pericopas` yo tengo dos columnas para delimitar de dónde a dónde va una referencia mediante las columnas `v_inicial` y `v_final`. En el ejemplo anterior la consulta me filtró bien los datos, trayéndome todos los textos entre `v_inicial = 14` y `v_final = 22`.

Pero hay casos irregulares, donde el contenido no va de un versículo a otro, sino que tiene saltos. Para esos casos, yo uso una tabla auxiliar llamada `biblia_pericopas_aux` que tiene un campo llamado `query` donde guardo lo que sería el criterio completo de la consulta.

Por ejemplo, un dato de la columna `query`:

```
(l=32 AND c=1) and ((v >=6 and v<=8) or (v >=19 and v<=28))
```

En la tabla `biblia_pericopas` esa filas con casos especiales están indicadas en una columna llamada `status_ref`, la cual es `1` cuando se trata de una perícopa con caso especial, o sea, que hay que buscar el criterio en la tabla auxiliar, y cuando no es un caso especial esa columna tiene un `0`.

Lo que quiero saber si podría modificar mi consulta anterior para que tome el criterio normal en caso de que `status_ref` sea `FALSE` o que tome el criterio que hay en `query` (de la tabla auxiliar) en caso de que `status_ref` sea `1`.

Comment: Algo así: `where .. and ( (status_ref is true and (<condicion1>) or (status_ref is false and (<condicion2>) )` o te entendí mal?

Comment: Gracias @PatricioMoracho, has entendido bien. Pero no me funciona en los casos en que debería tomar el criterio de la columna `query`. El criterio completo queda así: `WHERE  
    bp.id_pericopa=696 AND 
    l.id_celebracion=134 AND  
    lml.orden =1 AND (
      ( bp.estatus_ref=1 AND (bpa.query) )
      OR 
      ( bp.estatus_ref=0 AND (bcee.l=bp.id_libro AND bcee.c >= bp.capitulo AND bcee.v >= bp.v_inicial AND bcee.v <= bp.v_final) ) 
      )` . Funciona cuando no es un caso especial solamente. Las banderas son `0` y `1` realmente. Editaré la pregunta para que no haya confusiones.

Comment: Tiene que ser un query?? o puede ser un SP?? tiene toda la pinta de que un SP lo resolveria mucho mejor ,como para construir el query al vuelo...

Comment: @gbianchi puede ser también un SP. Ahora bien, no tengo casi ninguna experiencia en ese campo. Yo tengo que sacar textos de todo un año y busco la forma de automatizar el proceso, porque ahora mismo lo hago manualmente y se hace demasiado pesado. La idea es unir todas las tablas que aparecen en la consulta y traerme todos los textos según algunos criterios. Creo que la idea de SP sería genial.

Comment: Es que me suena a tu mejor opcion. Construir el where con el resultado de las tablas.. porque en realidad, un query no puede ejecutar el where con el resultado de otra tabla, tomando eso para ejecutarlo.. lo puede usar como consulta, pero no ejecutar el contenido.. O por lo menos, nunca en mi vida lo vi. Sin embargo, no tengo ni la mas palida idea de como constuir un SP en mysql y ni entorno para probarlo. :(

Comment: Igual, aunque interesante lo que tratas de hacer, no se si es lo mejor del mundo guardar un pedazo del query en una tabla.. ya que depende exclusivamente del query (o sea, c tiene que estar si o si definido en tu query). Entiendo lo que queres hacer.. pero tal vez, no seria mejor que eso fuera una vista que ya devolviera por ejemplo los id de los registros que queres, y meter esos en una clausula IN?

Comment: y otra cosa mas que se me ocurre, es que tu query se construya en la vista, usando exactamente eso que queres hacer en tu db...

Comment: @gbianchi no sé si es lo mejor. Yo opté por hacerlo así porque en los casos particulares necesito tres cosas: 1. consultar a la BD de forma diferente, usando criterios a veces complicados en los que hay que saltar para buscar textos de diferentes capítulos y versículos, por eso pensé que lo mejor era poner el criterio completo en una columna de la tabla auxiliar; 2. construir una referencia que tampoco es automática, porque lleva a veces una parte de un versículo que puede ser la primera parte (`a`), la segunda parte (`b`), etc. De modo que pongo esa referencia tal cual en otra columna...

Comment: ... de la tabla auxiliar, y 3. Tengo que construir una URL de forma dinámica también, que represente a ese texto en una página web. Dado que es también compleja según los casos y difícil de automatizar, he optado por ponerla en otra columna de la tabla auxiliar. O sea, con la tabla auxiliar estoy resolviendo esos tres problemas sin demasiadas complicaciones. Todo funciona bien, excepto en este caso en el que quiero sacar los diferentes textos de una forma masiva para usarlos en otro sitio. Quizá como dices, hay una mejor forma de hacerlo. Fue la mejor que encontré en su momento.